# Sci-fi book about two guys (one with a cybernetic arm) who fight shape-changers. The story also involves a race of cat-like telepaths

Tags: story-identification, books

I read this book; I think it was part two of a series from the '80s / '90s.

The main characters are a guy and his buddy, who has a cybernetic arm. They were fighting shape-changers and had no way to detect them. They heard about a race of cat-like people who were telepaths who could detect the shape-changers.  They go to the planet to see if they can convince the cat-like people to help them. When they get there, the first dude ends up married to one of the cat people because she had to trigger his mating instinct to stop a mental attack from a shape-changer.  His buddy had to go through the attack because they thought he was stronger, since he told them a story of how he lost his arm. Dude beats the guy who took his arm to death.

I feel like the book cover may have had a yellow grid on it, and a cat-looking golden lady with big green or blue eyes, plus a guy with a big visor over his eyes, and a metal arm, maybe.  This could possibly be a cyberpunk type of book, but it felt more general science fiction to me. Please help me find it.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you actually read this?

Comment: I'm pretty sure I read it in the 90s.  I can't pinpoint a time.  I may have been 12 or 13, so 1992 or 1993.  It was definitely before 1996 because I had it before my house caught fire and I lost all my books.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. If anyone correctly identifies the book you're looking for, you can mark that answer as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Comment: One of Larry Niven's Kzin stories?

Comment: Thank you for answering, but sadly no, not Larry Niven.  Though that does look interesting to read, I'm going to have to check it out.  The girl had feline features but she wasn't completely cat like - her face was very human with a few feline features like bigger eyes and pointier ears.  They had to go to her planet to see her. It was a jungle like planet and they were very tribe like. no advanced technology.

Comment: I immediately though of Joan D. Vinge's "Cat" series, which features a half human, half cat-alien telepath. Sadly, the plot doesn't match any of the books.